# 'Remove' button for cart

Tags: shopping-cart

Currently I have a UI similar to the following where +/- adjusts the quantity and reaching `0` removes the item altogether.

[image]

Having a separate `Remove` link/button would be *good* no doubt, but is it **essential** (eg. does it affect sales)? Has anyone researched/tested it already?

Comment: Are you also able to type into that number slot to make it say 0? If not, what if the user buy in bulk and has added x99 of 10 different items. They're going to be in there a while clicking down if not.

Comment: Does "0" remove the item from the list immediately? What if I've clicked the "-" one time too many by mistake? Can I click back to "1"? Or do I find the item again and re-add it?

Answer (score 1):

## Making it harder isn't nudging

I'd argue that once a user has decided to remove the item, making it harder for her isn't going to help. But it may annoy, which could eat away from  your site's emotional credits (or in extreme cases cause complete dismay).

## Why do we remove cart items?

It is worth considering the reasons people remove items from carts and work around these instead. For example, providing `remove` + `save for later` could increase sales.

Answer (score 0):

It would definitely affect the approach.From you post what i could senses is to remove the items from cart the user need to make quantity "zero".

If you go with that method - Negative

- For a particular item the quantity is 12.The user what to remove the item from the cart.Then user need to click (12 times) to remove item.

I would suggest to add delete icon for mobile / delete button if it is a web based app for each item.

Answer (score 0):

For a naive user, it would be really difficult to figure out that "minus" button has to be clicked to remove the item from cart.

Having a 'delete' icon/button is no harm and it has to be placed in a such a way that the user by mistake should not click & remove the item.

To answer your question, "Does it affect sales?" - NO. It works the opposite way. The user should always have a freedom to quit at any stage.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the lack of a remove button is more likely to affect sales. I've quite often, with impulsive purchases, just given up if I face frustrating order processes.

If I've added 10 of something, but changed my mind and chosen a different model  I'm unlikely to sit there pressing the minus buttons 10 times in a row.

I'm more likely to just close the site. I can probably buy those 10 things another day.

People aren't going to go through with purchases because it's difficult to change their mind, they're going to go through with purchases because it's easy. Once they've decided "Maybe I don't need this" a frustrating interface isn't going to swing them round to the "Okay, I need this!"

Imagine if you were in a store and you were browsing, then decided you didn't want an item - if the salesperson was to prevent you putting it down, would that make you more likely to go through with the purchase, or another one? (Incidentally, I've had people do this to me in Marrakech, it's incredibly frustrating).

A text box you can directly set "0" in would help, but I don't even want to fiddle around with a text box when there should just be a little delete icon.

Answer (score -1):

i've recently been involved in online sports betting something quite similar to what you are saying is when you make a bet with multiple games you can adjust the amount you are placing on a game with the text box and there is an X (close) button on each game that cancels it altogether. Check out the system bet on bet-at-home.com

Comment: We're concerned here more with the research and findings that then implementation itself.